# mysql relay log corrupted, How to recover?

Tags: mysql-replication

I am running with one master and two slaves in a chain. ie

```
Master-->Primary Slave-->Secondary Slave.
```

The relay log of primary slave got corrupted.

How can I recreate the relay log of primary slave without making any changes to the `Primary Slave --> Secondary Slave`  replication?

Comment: I doubt you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's the relay log (rather than the master bin log) which got corrupted, then

1. STOP SLAVE (on both slaves)
2. SHOW SLAVE STATUS on the failing machine to get the current log file and position
3. RESET SLAVE on the faling machine
4. CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_LOG_FILE='filename from step 2', MASTER_LOG_POS='position from step 2'
5. START SLAVE on both slaves